# Issue with EmailJS function - No API Response and Console.log Output

Tags: javascript

I am facing an issue with the emailJS library. I created a function to send a copy of a transaction to an email address using emailJS. However, the API is not receiving any response and I am not getting any output to the console.log. It seems like the function is not even being called. I am not sure what I did wrong and I think it might be a simple fix that I overlooked.

here is the config.js file which contains the user keys and function for mailer i removed all the keys and put in place what belongs there as an fyi to anyone thinking i forgot to fill in the keys

```
function sendEmail(name, address, city, state, zip, phone, email, amount) {
    // Initialize EmailJS with your user ID
    emailjs.init("public-key-here");
  
    // Create the email parameters
    var templateParams = {
      name: name,
      address: address,
      city: city,
      state: state,
      zip: zip,
      phone: phone,
      email: email,
      amount: amount
    };
  
    // Send the email using EmailJS
    emailjs.send("service_ID", "template_ID, templateParams)
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log("Email sent successfully");
        alert("Mail send success");
      }, function(error) {
        console.log("Email failed to send", error);
        alert("Error sending mail");
      });
  }
```

And here is the send email function being called on the payment page

```
 // Send email with transaction record and save order details to local storage
                  sendEmail(name, address, city, state, zip, phone, email, amount);
                  localStorage.setItem('orderDetails', JSON.stringify({
                    amount: parseFloat(amount),
                    name: name,
                    address: address,
                    city: city,
                    state: state,
                    zip: zip,
                    phone: phone,
                    email: email
                  }));
```

I get no output in my console.log and or alert that email was success or not. Any help please

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved my issue! I discovered that I needed to wrap the window.location.href that's called after submitting payment in a setTimeout() function which now delays by 3 seconds when the user is taken to the thank-you page. After making this change, everything is now working perfectly. Sorry i did not provide the full code but the error was not in the code i provided above it was in the code on my payment page where i have a function that takes user to new page after successful payment. The emailjs function did not have enough time to complete because it was loading the success page to fast which is why i was not getting the emails or any console.log output

```
setTimeout(function() {
  window.location.href = "thankyou.html";
}, 3000);  // 3 second delay in milliseconds
```